# Youtube - How to get all videos from user channel with PHP, JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, youtube

Maybe I am over looking something, but from all the API docs I've looked at theres no mention that I have found as of yet or examples to show if youtube offers channel specific feeds

what I want to do ultimately is with a little bit of php and javascript get all the videos for this particular user

http://www.youtube.com/user/stevesattlerfilms

and then list them out on his site accordingly. So seeing as I am having troubles finding my answers I decided to come here, I figure this may be a repeat question somehow somewhere and if it is I am sorry. But if anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be helpful enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would request a [video feed](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Videos_feed) and make use of the [author parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Standard_parameters). This should give you all the videos of a specific user.

In your example: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=stevesattlerfilms