# Pull the latest video from a Youtube Channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, feed

Is there any way to pull only the latest video from a Youtube channel using Javascript?

[I've got an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869839/youtube-how-to-get-all-videos-from-user-channel-with-php-javascript-and-jquer) of using Youtube feed but I don't really know how to implement it using javascript.

Any practical example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a hard searching this morning, I now get it work perfectly:

```
$(function() {  
   var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   var PLAYLIST_ID = 'PLDvUaV28ulciewonYGknOdIw8lAJfXIzn';

   var GOOGLE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2C+snippet%2C+contentDetails&playlistId='+PLAYLIST_ID+ '&key=' + API_KEY + '&callback=showVideos';

   $.ajax({
    url: GOOGLE_API_URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true
   });

   window.showVideos = function(data) {
    if (data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
       $("#video").html('<iframe width="504" height="283" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data.items[0].contentDetails.videoId+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: you should hide the api key from this site.

Comment: Where do you get the PLAYLIST_ID? I assume it just represents the "latest videos" page on the channel?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=yourchannel&orderby=published', function(data) {

   //data represents JSON Object of videos

}
```

If I set the parameters right, data should represents all videos sort by published time, so the last one is the latest one